# Show missing end-of-command semicolon as error for SQL in VS Code

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio Code to treat a missing semicolon at the end of an MSSQL command as an error or highlight with a warning? I don't see anything about this in the settings.

For what it's worth, I'm working offline, so I'm not connected to SQL Server.

Thanks.